# Read value of variable with the variable name

Tags: java, string, integer

I have a string which contains the name of a integer variable, like this:

```
int branchControlFlow1 = 2;
String branchField = "branchControlFlow1";
```

Is possible access the value of the variable branchControlFlow1 using the string (branchField) that contains the name of the variable?

The variable "branchControlFlow1" must necessarily be of integer type.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ***really*** use a map/arraylist of integers instead. Maps are key(string or any object) to value, while lists(arraylist or linked list) are int->Entry.

If not, you need to resort to <strike>dark magic</strike> reflection. I'll explain this witchcraft below. I do *not* take responsibility for headaches, nausea, electrocution, asphyxiation, drowning, forced drowning by 1600s lawmakers, any exceptions, any damages, incidental, or consequential, or other problems.

On a more serious note, this incurs a nasty performance penalty if called often or in time-critical code. Minimize reflection by assigning the value you get instead of getting it each time you need it.

First get an instance of the class object. If the field is in class called `FooClass`, use:

```
Class clazz=FooClass.class;
Field fd=clazz.getField(name);
int val=fd.getInt(myObjectOfFooClass);
```

You can't do this for local variables on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

You can lookup up fields by name using reflections.

However, if you trying to this a Map is more likely to be the best choice.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = ... 
map.put("branchControlFlow1", 2);
int num = map.get("branchControlFlow1");
```